# Android Maps API V2 Google Copyrights Notice Not Visible in Map View

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to ensure that Google Maps Copyright Notice always shows up on the map, but it does not.

Only the Google logo gets displayed. I tried setting the map padding as well but that does not seem to help.

It is a requirement that the copyright notices should be visible in maps (section 8.5 of https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

I'm using Google Maps API V2 for Android.

Has anyone encountered this problem and how how did you go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a call to the open source software license info as part of the google play services and show it using a menu item in the action bar or settings menu...

Like this:

`String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
      getApplicationContext());
      AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
      LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
      LicenseDialog.show();
         return true;`

The problem I am having with this method is the string is huge and takes forever to load...

EDIT:
A MUCH faster way to do this is to make it load in a webview:

`String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(act);
                LicenseInfo = LicenseInfo.replace("\n", "<br>");
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
                alert.setTitle("Legal Notices");
                WebView wv = new WebView(act);
                wv.loadData(LicenseInfo, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                alert.setView(wv);
                alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();`

Comment: Thank you Justin. Sorry I just looked at your answer but will try it out